# Difference between process group and job?

Tags: process, job-control, process-groups

What's the difference between a process group and a job? If I type `pr * | lpr` then is it both a process group as well a job? 
What exactly is the difference between a process group ID and a job ID?

Edit: I know it appears similar to [What is the difference between a job and a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/what-is-the-difference-between-a-job-and-a-process), but it is slightly different. Also, I didn't understand this concept from this thread.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) is a unix kernel concept. It doesn't come up very often. You can send a signal to all the processes in a group, by calling the `kill` [system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html) or [utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/kill.html) with a negative argument.

When a process is created (with [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html)), it remains in the same process group as its parent. A process can move into another group by calling [`setpgid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setpgid.html) or [`setpgrp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setpgrp.html). This is normally performed by the shell when it starts an external process, before it executes [`execve`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execve.html) to load the external program.

The main use for process groups is that when you press [`Ctrl+C`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29), [`Ctrl+Z`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTSTP) or [`Ctrl+\`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGQUIT) to [kill or suspend programs in a terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29#Sending_signals), the terminal sends a signal to a whole process group, the [foreground process group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_183). The details are fairly complex and mostly of interest to shell or kernel implementers; the [General Terminal Interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html) chapter of the POSIX standard is a good presentation (you do need some unix programming background).

Jobs are an internal concept to the shell. In the simple cases, each job in a shell corresponds to a process group in the kernel.