# How do processes, jobs and session relate to each other ?

Tags: shell, process, session, jobs

Could you deliver an answer in a way that does not require too much special knowledge in advance, yet also deliver some deeper insight to a lesser advanced Linux User ?

Comment: Something like... *the process bone is connected to the job bone* then?

Comment: The logical structure of the explanation can be as complicated as one please, the problem I face is, that many explanations contain unexplained KeyConcepts which most likely contain KeyConcepts to understand them, this way to understand even simple ideas is for the lesser Knowledgable like a fight with a hydra. Compare it too learning Chinese, a Beginner of Chinese is not stupid because he can not grasp the content of a story for children in Chinese, but because he does not know the words conveying it. I know some concepts but not enough to read and understand.

Comment: I'm closing this question as a duplicate of an [earlier, very similar one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/what-is-the-difference-between-a-job-and-a-process). (In the future, please **search** before asking — this question was easy to find by searching for `process job session` on this site.) There may be things that you don't understand after reading the answers there; if so, feel free to ask a more specific question about the part you don't understand.

Comment: I agree - no one implied stupid anything. And kids aren't stupid either just because they have good taste in music.

Comment: @Gilles , I read this answer before I opened this one

Comment: So what part of it don't you understand? Tell us! Otherwise, we'll just repeat the part you don't understand, which wastes both our time and yours.

Comment: I need to know about the functional and topological relationship between all three of them. functional: Which functions makes a process, session and job what they are. topological: Is one of them a subset of another, do one of them have to start one of the other, can they exist independently from each other, do they build structures together with special functions...

Comment: I think @Gilles was suggesting you edit that information into the question.

Comment: could you suggest a good format for a question, i fear it will be rejected for beeing too long. at a pinch, this question can be deleted and I think about a way to make it suitable.

Comment: Are you talking to @Gilles or just at nobody in particular? If the latter, maybe take it to meta? For myself, I rather liked the *job bone* format.

Comment: yes, I understood that Gilles has the power to close this question, I feel now at a loss, I fear I know even too less to produce a question that will be valid at this point.